# How to update values in .resx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, resources

In my controller I take all the values from a view that I want to change in .resx file, but it is not working - The values remain the same in .resx file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CustimizeSample(FormCollection fc)
    {
        string formname = Request.Form["formname"];
        var lablename = Request.Form["lablename"];
        var hintname = Request.Form["hintname"];
        var buttonname = Request.Form["buttonname"];
        Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Form_Name.Replace(@Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Form_Name, formname);
        Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_lable_Sample_Name.Replace(@Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_lable_Sample_Name, lablename);
        Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Hint_Name.Replace(@Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Hint_Name, hintname);
        Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Button_Name.Replace(@Resources.Resource1.InsertSample_Button_Name, buttonname);

        return View();
    }
```

And this is my View in which I take input from user for change values in .resx file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 var reader = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\CarResources.resx");//same fileName
 var node = reader.GetEnumerator();
 var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(@"C:\CarResources.resx");//same fileName(not new)
 while (node.MoveNext())
         {
     writer.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value.ToString());
       }
  var newNode = new ResXDataNode("Title", "Classic American Cars");
  writer.AddResource(newNode);
  writer.Generate();
  writer.Close();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.